# Tkinter - cannot move canvas on mainwindow

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning tkinter and I have created a simple converter. I have created a canvas and put all my widges on it. My main window is 800x640 and the canvas is 400x320. After I was done I wanted to play with the grid command and find a position for my canvas that I like. However when I do canvas.grid(row=rownr, column=columnnr) the canvas just goes to row=0, column=0 on the mainwindow no matter what values for row and col I give in the grid method. 
If I add another widget for example a label on the mainwindow at (0,0) then I try moving the canvas to (0,1) then the canvas goes to that position. However if the canvas is the only widget on my main window it won't move at all with grid method. Please help me understand why this happens. Here is the entire code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Menu


def convert_meters():
    # get value from entry and convert it to all
    result_in_meters = int(label1_1.get())# integer value
    result_in_km.set(float(result_in_meters/1000))
    result_in_dem.set(float(result_in_meters*10))
    result_in_miles.set(float(result_in_meters*0.000621371))
    result_in_yards.set(float(result_in_meters*1.09361))


def get_value_and_convert():
    if(combo1.get()=="meters"):
        convert_meters()
    elif(combo1.get()=="centimeters"):
        convert_centimeters()
    elif(combo1.get()=="millimeters"):
        convert_millimeters()
    elif(combo1.get()=="inches"):
        convert_inches()
    else:
        result_in_km.set("0")
        result_in_dem.set("0")
        result_in_miles.set("0")
        result_in_yards.set("0")

window = Tk()
window.title("Converter")
result = IntVar()

result_in_km = StringVar()
result_in_dem = StringVar()
result_in_miles = StringVar()
result_in_yards = StringVar()

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=400, height=320, bd=1, highlightthickness=1, relief='ridge')
canvas1.grid(row=2, column=2)

#### Things to convert #####
label1 = Label(canvas1, text="Convert ", width=8)
label1_1 = Entry(canvas1, width=2) # between label1 and combobox
combo1 = Combobox(canvas1, width=8)
combo1['values'] = ("meters","centimeters","millimeters","inches")
combo1.current(0)
label2 = Label(canvas1, text=" to:", width=10)
############################

#### Convert to: ####
label3 = Label(canvas1, text="Km: ", width=10)
label4 = Label(canvas1, text="Dem: ", width=10)
label5 = Label(canvas1, text="Miles: ", width=10)
label6 = Label(canvas1, text="Yards: ", width=10)
#####################

#### Displaying labels ####
display1 = Label(canvas1, textvariable=result_in_km, width=40, relief=SUNKEN)
display2 = Label(canvas1, textvariable=result_in_dem, width=40, relief=SUNKEN)
display3 = Label(canvas1, textvariable=result_in_miles, width=40, relief=SUNKEN)
display4 = Label(canvas1, textvariable=result_in_yards, width=40, relief=SUNKEN)
###########################

#### The convert button ####
convert_button = Button(canvas1, width=40, text="Convert", command=get_value_and_convert)
############################

label1_window = canvas1.create_window(100, 10, anchor=NW, window=label1)
label1_1_window = canvas1.create_window(160, 10, anchor=NW, window=label1_1)
combo1_window = canvas1.create_window(200, 10, anchor=NW, window=combo1)
label2_window = canvas1.create_window(300, 10, anchor=NW, window=label2)

label3_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 80, anchor=NW, window=label3)
display1_window = canvas1.create_window(60, 80, anchor=NW, window=display1)

label4_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 120, anchor=NW, window=label4)
display2_window = canvas1.create_window(60, 120, anchor=NW, window=display2)

label5_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 160, anchor=NW, window=label5)
display3_window = canvas1.create_window(60, 160, anchor=NW, window=display3)


label6_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 200, anchor=NW, window=label6)
display4_window = canvas1.create_window(60, 200, anchor=NW, window=display4)

display5_window = canvas1.create_window(50, 250, anchor=NW, window=convert_button)


window.geometry('800x640')


window.mainloop()
```

And this is the line in which I tried positioning the canvas with grid(it's right after declaring the canvas):

```
canvas1.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty rows and columns have size 0.

If you just want to move the canvas around you could use padding:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x640')

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=400, height=320, bd=1,
                 highlightthickness=1, relief='ridge', bg='khaki')
canvas1.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=50, pady=100)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you figbeam. This was exactly what I was looking for.